# What happens if I mix green and orange coolant in a 2008 Chevy cobalt?

Tags: chevrolet, cooling-system, cobalt

It’s a 2008 Chevy cobalt ss. I recently bought the car from a friend, and it sat for awhile before I bought it. I’m now trying to update all its needs, and I wasn’t sure what coolant was in it to begin with. I was told it had green coolant/antifreeze in it. But I had bought the orange kind. 50/50 (did not need to add water. Ready to use). I’m concerned that I might have messed but and I need some help please

Answer (score 0):

Generally you shouldn't mix coolants, but really you've not killed anything. You've mixed two kinds of fluid which makes for ugly coolant. Green coolant is good for around 2 years, while the orange coolant (orange is usually a Dexcool variant, which is probably what should have been in your car in the first place) usually has a change interval of 5 years or 150k miles. They are two different types. When you mix them, you've basically reduced the orange coolant down to the green coolant longevity. By mixing the two you'll have not damaged the cooling system any, so don't worry too much about it at this point. When you get a chance and the means to do so, completely flush the system and put the correct coolant type in and you'll be golden.

**NOTE:** Some will argue you should never mix coolants. I personally have never found verifiable information showing where there's an issue doing so. Most is internet conjecture.

Comment: I have now started to have issues with my car starting. Is this because of the coolant being mixed?

Comment: @HarleyOthersen - Your coolant should have absolutely nothing to do with your car starting, unless the vehicle was allowed to overheat because of lack of coolant. If your car had zero coolant, you would be able to start your engine, though you wouldn't want to run it for too long. Mixing coolant would not cause you starting issues whatsoever.